# output problems while generating Microsoft Word ML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, ml

When i execute my code, to copy nodes with their attributes, not, all of node attributes are copied

for example  the input in Microsoft Word ML:-

```
<w:tblPr><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblBorders><w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/><w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/><w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/><w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/><w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/><w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="10" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/></w:tblBorders><w:tblLook w:val="00BF"/></w:tblPr>
```

whem i run my code, the output will be

```
<w:tblPr><w:tblW w:w="0"/><w:tblBorders><w:top w:val="single"/><w:left w:val="single"/><w:bottom w:val="single"/><w:right w:val="single"/><w:insideH w:val="single"/><w:insideV w:val="single"/></w:tblBorders><w:tblLook w:val="00BF"/></w:tblPr>
```

There are some missing attributes which are not copied, when they are missed, i can't open the file in Microsoft Word.

IF someone could help me, and point out what is wrong with my code. or what i should do to solve this problem. My code as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" media-type="application/html+xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:variable name="extNode" select="document('document4.xml') "/><!--  Document --><!--
 Copy Element
 Reprocesses Element in the output document:
 Copies Attributes
Copies Text
Copies Child Nodes
--><!-- Copy Attribute -->
<xsl:template name="copy-attribute">
<xsl:param name="attribute"/>
<xsl:if test="$attribute">
<xsl:attribute name="{name($attribute)}">
<xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:variable name="Temp">
<xsl:if test="name()">
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="($Temp ='Place-Holder')">
<xsl:text>whatever text here simulating xml file</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:if test=".">
<xsl:element name="{name(.)}"><!-- Copy Attributes -->
<xsl:call-template name="copy-attribute">
<xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="./@*"/>
</xsl:call-template><!-- Copy Text -->
<xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
<w:wordDocument w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags">
<xsl:for-each select="$extNode/w:wordDocument/child::node()"><!-- Microsoft word document design such as style,font,lists...etc -->
<xsl:if test=" name(.) != 'w:body'">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if><!-- MS document body where contents will be merged here-->
<xsl:if test="name(.) ='w:body'"><!-- MS document that contains contents,must have "Place-Holder" tag, so it will be known where to add contents-->
<w:body>
<xsl:for-each select="./child::node()">
<xsl:variable name="Temp">
<xsl:if test=".//Place-Holder">
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="position() != $Temp">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = $Temp">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</w:body>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</w:wordDocument>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think the problem in copy-attribute template function.

Comment: there are some missing attributes from output file

Comment: It is not clear what is the question. Also, if you consider this to be XSLT problem, you need to show a small XML document, the exact desired result, the unwanted result you are getting and why the result you are getting is incorrect. Leaving people without information leads to receiving no meaningful answers. Please, edit the question and provide this necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  i modified this part

```
    <xsl:template name="copy-attribute">
    <xsl:param name="attribute"/>
    <xsl:if test="$attribute">  
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>

         </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Regards,